# How do additional songs work on the Wii version of Rock Band 3?

Tags: nintendo-wii, rock-band-3

I know that former iterations of both this game and Guitar Hero games provided "expansion discs" or something of that nature to release some of the songs that were available as DLC for the Wii console, since they were unable to be downloaded through some kind of marketplace which was available on the Xbox 360 and the PS3.

However, when loading up Rock Band 3 for the Wii, there is an option on the main menu to procure extra music (although I don't remember the exact phrasing).  How does this option work?  Is the Wii now capable of the same kind of system that had already been in place on the other two consoles?

Comment: The Wii's problem has never been one of interface -- the Shopping Channel duplicates Xbox Live and PlaystationNetwork -- but of memory. The Wii doesn't have an internal hard drive (though it does have a usb port).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wii has had access to the Rock Band store since the release of Rock Band 2.  Your Wii needs to be connected to the Internet, and you need regular Wii points in order to purchase the songs.  The usual price is 200 points per song, but there are some priced at 100 points.

Also, due to the lack of a hard drive, you will want a good sized SD card in the Wii in order to store the songs.  I have a 2GB in mine, but that is because Rock Band 2 does not support a larger card, even though the Wii does.  My guess is that Rock Band 3 will support larger SD cards.

Comment: Does the Wii have a SD slot or do you mean USB?

Comment: @Strix - the Wii has an SD slot.  There is a small door between the reset and eject buttons.  The slot is in there.